# Maximum Value Based on a Condition

Tags: excel, max

I have a mock dataset in Excel that I want to print the most recent date, but I want it to be the latest date such that the Type is "referral":

```
Type      Date
referral  1/6/2017
classroom 1/7/2017
referral  1/8/2017
classroom 1/9/2017
```

What would that function look like?

Comment: Use the Max function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array formula like this (assuming your columns are A and B):

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A5="referral",B2:B5))
```

and enter it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

When entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Excel will put curly brackets around it like this:

```
{=MAX(IF(A2:A5="referral",B2:B5))}
```

Note that you cannot type the brackets "{ }" yourself.

Also, as Scott Craner points out, you should limit the ranges in an array formula so as to prevent iterating through an entire column (e.g., I've edited to have A2:A5 instead of A:A).

Here it is in action:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:B5/(A2:A5="referral"),1)
```

If you have Office 365 Excel then use this formula which is not an array type:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,"referral")
```

[image]